# Scrollview not showing views

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I have an recyclerview where I show my data. Part of the recyclerviewitem is a scrollview.
[image: recyclerview design]

So I fill the recyclerview with data and set a picture and text within the holder. I also want to add pictures to the scrollview there.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SchritteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = schritte[position]

       holder.rezeptePicView.setImageDrawable( ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,current.alg.bild))
        var text = ""
        for( zut in zutatenforSchritte[position]) {
            val imageViewzut = ImageView(this.context)
            val textView = TextView(this.context)
            imageViewzut.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,zut.bild))
            textView.text = zut.zutname
            text =text + zut.zutname
            holder.scrollViewSchritte.addView(imageViewzut)
            holder.scrollViewSchritte.addView(textView)
        }
        holder.rezepteItemView.text = current.alg.text + " " + current.sp.temperatur + " " +current.sp.zeit +" " + current.sp.sonst +text
    }
```

The data is there because I can fill it in the text an picture and text are there, but the scrollview stays empty.
[image: filled recyclerview]

I have no idea why the scrollview stays empty. So if you know what could be the reasons tips would be nice.

Comment: Add your xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, scrollview waws the wrn gway to go. I added an other recyclerview just showing an icon.

So the outer Recyclerview looks like this:

```
class SchritteSmallListAdapterJustShow internal constructor(
    context: Context
): RecyclerView.Adapter<SchritteSmallListAdapterJustShow.SchritteViewHolder>(){

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var schritte = emptyList<SpezSchrittWithAlg>()
    val contextfu = context
    private var zutatenforSchritte :MutableList<List<ZutatenData>> =emptyList<List<ZutatenData>>().toMutableList()

    inner class SchritteViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val rezepteItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSmallschritt)
        val rezeptePicView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewschritt)
        var recycler: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewforIcons)
        val adapter = ZutatenIconShowAdapter(contextfu)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SchritteViewHolder {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_schritte, parent, false)
        return  SchritteViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SchritteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = schritte[position]

       holder.rezeptePicView.setImageDrawable( ContextCompat.getDrawable(contextfu,current.alg.bild))
        holder.rezepteItemView.text = current.alg.text + " " + current.sp.temperatur + " " +current.sp.zeit +" " + current.sp.sonst
        holder.recycler.adapter = holder.adapter
        holder.recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(contextfu, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        holder.recycler.layoutMode
        holder.adapter.setZutaten(zutatenforSchritte[position])

    }

    internal fun setSchritte(rez : List<SpezSchrittWithAlg>){
        schritte = rez
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    internal fun setZutatenliste(zutaten  : MutableList<List<ZutatenData>>){
        zutatenforSchritte = zutaten
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =schritte.size
}
```

And the inner Recyclerview looks like this:

```
class ZutatenIconShowAdapter internal constructor(
    context: Context
): RecyclerView.Adapter<ZutatenIconShowAdapter.ZutatenViewHolder>(){

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var zutaten = emptyList<ZutatenData>()
    private val context = context

    inner class ZutatenViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val rezeptePicView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.smallIconview)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ZutatenViewHolder {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_just_icon, parent, false)
        return  ZutatenViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ZutatenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = zutaten[position]
        holder.rezeptePicView.setImageDrawable( ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,current.bild))

    }

    internal fun setZutaten(zutats: List<ZutatenData>){
        zutaten= zutats
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =zutaten.size
}
```

Which got me the result I wanted:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify which implementation of LayoutParams you are using.

additionally you can show only **one** item in scrollview.

```
holder.scrollViewSchritte.layoutParams(LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```